# How can i parse to TextField iOS Keychain in Swift?

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I saved my account through Locksmith Keychain, everything works fine, right now i need to parse the data stored to a textField, how can i do it please?
Here is the code that i use to save my account:

```
let accountsave = Locksmith.saveData(["account": self.txtAccount.text], forUserAccount: "myUserAccount", inService: "myAccount").
```

Right now i need to parse the data store to a textfield in swift. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand of your question you're asking for something similar to this:

```
let (dictionary, error) = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount("myUserAccount", inService: "myAccount")
if let userData = dictionary as? [String:String] {
    if let account = userData["account"] {
        self.txtAccount.text = account
    }
}
```

Comment: i have this error in the second line : 'NSDictionary? does not have a ember named 'subcript'

Comment: Check my answer again, I forgot to unwrap the optional value.

Comment: I have another problem, try to see if you can help me to resolve it. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972336/fatal-error-array-index-out-of-range-in-uitableview-on-back-to-previous-control?noredirect=1#comment48064812_29972336